# How to get local time from web server

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ajax, server

I have set up an AJAX server with these settings:

```
    let express = require('express');
    let server = express();

    server.use('/MyWebApp', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

    server.get('/MyWebApp/dateService', function(request, response){        
        response.send({'dateTime' : new Date()});
    });

    server.listen(2019);
    console.log('server running on port 2019 ...')
```

I want to get the local time and have this function in my HTML:

```
function getDateTime(){

                $.get({

                    url: "http://localhost:2019/MyWebApp/dateService",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(result){
                        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = result;
                    }
                }); 
            }
```

But when I click the button, it doesn't work and I don't know why.

```
<div id="timer">Random Text</div>

<input type="button" value="Server-Request" onclick="getDateTime()"/>
```

The div is suppose to change to the local time but I get error

> jquery.min.js:6 GET http://localhost:2019/MyWebApp/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)

If I change the function into this, it works perfectly!

```
function getTime(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: "http://localhost:2019/MyWebApp/dateService",
                    async: true,
                    dataType: 'text',
                    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){    
                    document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = "Current Time:" + data + " Status: " + textStatus;
                    }
                });

            }
```

And this Endpoint:

```
server.get('/MyWebApp/dateService', function(request, response){        
    response.send(new Date(Date.now()).toISOString());
});
```

But my point is that I want to send JSON.

Comment: "it doesn't work" — What does that mean? What happens? How is that different from what you expect to happen? Are any errors displayed in the browser Console? Or the Node.js console? Does the browser's Network tab show the request being made? Is it as you expect? Does it get any response? Does that response contain the data you expect?

Comment: Does an error occur?

Comment: (There are several obvious errors with your code, and several more potential problems).

Comment: If you `console.log(result)`  in your `success` callback, what is the returned value?

Comment: Just wondering: Why do you need call out for the current time? What's wrong with new Date() or Date.current?

Answer (score 0):

You can't send a working object via JSON like you're trying to with

```
response.send({'dateTime' : new Date()});
```

HTML responses like this are strings.  If you try to send an object, it will attempt to make a string out of it.

And, since the client-side looks like it expects a string that you can insert directly into your HTML, what I'd suggest you do on the server is this:

```
server.get('/MyWebApp/dateService', function(request, response){        
    let now = new Date();
    res.send(now.toGMTString());     // or pick your favorite string format
});
```

Or, look at the [various ways the current date can be formatted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toGMTString) and pick a different string format.

and, then change your ajax call to expect a string back:

```
       function getDateTime(){
            $.get({url: "http://localhost:2019/MyWebApp/dateService"}).then(function(result) {
                  document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = result;
            }).catch(function(err) {
                  // decide what to do if you get an error
                  console.log(err);
            });
        }
```

Note: this gets the time on the server.  If you just want the current time for the user, you don't need to ask the server for that.  You can use a `Date` object in your local browser Javascript to get the client computer's time.